# Why does IoU as metrics for Semantic Segmentation raise a values error in Keras?

Tags: conv-neural-network, semantic-segmentation, model-fitting, keras-metrics

Applying a binary semantic segmentation model ( "unet", tensorflow.keras) with classes 0 and 1, works well when compiled as follows, with metrics "accuracy" or "Binary Crossentropy"

> unet.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-3),
> loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
> metrics =
> [tf.keras.metrics.BinaryIoU(target_class_ids=[1], name="IoU")])

It does not work when I attempt to use BinaryIoU as metrics as in the code above
In that case, **model.fit** raises a value mismatch error.  The traceback concludes as follows:

> Node: 'confusion_matrix/stack_1'
> Shapes of all inputs must match: values[0].shape = [4194304] != values[1].shape = [8388608]
> [[{{node confusion_matrix/stack_1}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_24084]

In other words, there is a factor of 2 difference in shape of values[0] and values[1]. I suspect that values[0] pertains to the true mask and values[1] to the predicted mask. But I do not understand sufficiently Keras **model.fit** to know how the error originates.

The shape of my image and masks is (512, 512, 1).  Masks dtype is uint16.
Thanks for educating me.